# Page Table Size

Tags: memory-management, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory

I am given the following information:

**Virtual address: 32 bits**

**Physical address: 30 bits**

**Page size: 8 KB**

**Page table entry: 4 bytes**

I am trying to calculate the size of the page table. Is the page table size calculated by using the virtual address space or physical address space?

Virtual:
2^32 / 2^13 = 2^19 Pages * 2^2 Entry Size = **2^21 Page Table Size**

Physical:
2^30 / 2^13 = 2^17 Pages * 2^2 Entry Size = **2^19 Page Table Size**

Because of the differences in address size, I am unsure if the physical memory address space will constrain the larger virtual address space.

I greatly appreciate any help on which one of these approaches is correct given the limited information the problem provides.

Comment: similar topic? [questions/4029838/determine-page-table-size-for-virtual-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029838/determine-page-table-size-for-virtual-memory)

Comment: Ask yourself what a page table is used for. Hint: it's either for mapping virtual pages to physical pages, or it's for mapping physical pages to virtual pages (but generally not both). If you know which of those is correct, that should tell you how many individual mappings you need to cover an entire address space, and from there you can figure out how much memory a full page table would occupy...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know which of those is correct. My guess would be that the size of the table only needs to accommodate the physical address space.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever gave you the question, gave you one without an answer. People ask this same question with no answer repeatedly. I'd love to know the source.

The question reflects a fundamental lack of understanding of the structure of a page table.

It would be impossible to implement a page table without a system address space. The question gives no explanation of how the address space is divided because user and system. That makes the question nonsensical.

The physical limits would not affect the page table size if the page table is pageable itself.

The virtual limits are just limits. A page table does not have to (and rare does) span the entire virtual address space. The virtual address space would only set a high end for the size.

I sure hope this question is not in a textbook.

Answer (score 1):

The physical address size (30 bits) is a red herring.

If you have 32 bit virtual addresses, and each page is 8KB (2^13), then 2^(32-13) pages are required to store every virtual address.

The size of the page table is 2^(32-13) = 2^19 page addresses mulitplied by the number of bytes per entry, so:

Page Table Size = (2^19)*4 = 2 MB

2^19 * 1 byte is 1/2 MB

EDIT:
To answer your question, you use the virtual address space.